# NET Core error on macOS when I try to run an ASP Net app

Tags: asp.net, .net, macos, .net-core

I'm having this problem when I try to run an ASP Net app on my Mac M1. I run this app on my other PC (Win 10) and now I'm switching to Mac.

This is the console response: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/Users/facundomartinez/Documents/ASP_Local_x64_01/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.

- The application was run as a self-contained app because '/Users/facundomartinez/Documents/ASP_Local_x64_01/TGD_Soft_Apis.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
- If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '/Users/facundomartinez/Documents/ASP_Local_x64_01/TGD_Soft_Apis.runtimeconfig.json'.
  facundomartinez@MacBook-Pro-de-Facundo ASP_Local_x64_01 %

I hope there's a solution, or a simply one. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: You have to check that the .NET SDK for ARM64 is installed on your Mac M1. Check and update your project's target framework to be compatible with ARM64. Edit the 'runtimeconfig.json' file to specify the appropriate framework.

Comment: Yes, I checked and it's correct. The runtimeconfig.json has the same version that I have installed. But, when I exceute dotnet name_of_app.dll it says something like: "You need to install or update .NET Core version" and the version that is needed is '3.1.5' which is no longer available. I don't know what to do. Can I share more information, maybe.